# Sending the data from one webapplication to different web application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, web-applications

I am using java/GWT/GXT/Spring and Hibernate. I have two webapplications deployed in tomcat as below.

```
WebApp1 - is webapplication with GWT/Spring/Hibernate
WebApp2 - is webapplication with JSF and spring
```

Now i have to send some data from `WebApp1` to `WebApp2` and that data has to be displayed in one screen which is there in `WebApp2`. For that i can provide a link in `WebApp1` to `WebApp2`. **My question is is it possible to send data from one web application to another web application?**

```
WebApp1 will have a link to WebApp2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For platform independent data representation was invented the xml. Use it! A simple HTTP Post and is done.
If you want to optimize and take off the overhead, you can that too.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a shared resource where you can store the information in between. For Example Database, File, System, JNDI-Tree, JMS,  etc.

Be careful with accessing those resources, especially file system needs a synchronization.

a direct communication via JVM is not possible.

You can also use a REST Service to get the information transfered. 
Example: WEB-APP2 needs infos from WEB-APP1, then WEB-APP2 calls Service inside WEB-APP1

If you try to build two independent views on the same dataset you have to use shared resource like I mentioned already.

Comment: Do u mean, on click of WebApp2 link in WebApp1, do i need to save the data in database and access it in WebApp2 ?

Comment: I am not sure what are you planing exactly, could you explain the use case ?

Comment: if you just plan to show a screen from webapp2 in wappapp1 I would use an iframe in webapp1 which point to the link in webapp2. If you like to do more with the data I would prefer an other way

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, try out Spring Web Services

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/

It will allow you to speak in terms of java object from both ends.  Internally it converts request to XML Soap messages but this is transparent to you as the programmer and won't have to worry about it.

I got it working using the JAXB Marshaller using STS.  You can right click on the xml schema file and select the jaxb option to generate the object automatically for you.  So in the end, the only thing you need to generate youself is the XML Schema file.  Spring WebServices can automatically generate the .wdsl for you also.